# How many simple graphs with 5 vertices of degree 2 do we have?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

does anyone know any formula to calculate number of simple graphs with **n** specific number of vertices that each one of vertices have a degree of **m**(like 2 or four or etc)

note : suppose we **n = 5(number of vertices)** and **m = 2(degree for  each one of vertices)**

How many simple graphs do we have with that information?

Comment: Do you need them up to isomorphism or not?

Comment: @Exodd i need all of them to have the same degree

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if every vertex has degree $2$, your graph is the union of disjoint cycles.

Comment: What if  every vertex have degree of 4 . note : we have 5 vertices

Comment: Then every vertex is joined to every other vertex, so ...